# The difference between DataLine and (Output|Input)Stream?

Tags: java, stream

I am working on sound processing with the use of Java now. Within my project, I have to deal with the stream. So I have a lot of staffs to do with `DataLine` and `OutputStream` or `InputStream`. 
But to me, they are too similar:(

Is there someone who can help me with this question? Thanks in advance!
Here are some code I used ：

```
        TargetDataLine line;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int frameSizeInBytes = format.getFrameSize();
        int bufferLengthInFrames = line.getBufferSize() / 8;
        int bufferLengthInBytes = bufferLengthInFrames * frameSizeInBytes;
        byte[] data = new byte[bufferLengthInBytes];
        int numBytesRead;
try {
        line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        line.open(format, line.getBufferSize());
    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        shutDown("Unable to open the line: " + ex);
        return;
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        shutDown(ex.toString());
        return;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        shutDown(ex.toString());
        return;
    }
       line.start();
       while (thread != null) {
            if ((numBytesRead = line.read(data, 0, bufferLengthInBytes)) == -1) {
                break;
        }
        out.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
       }
```

I have read the documentation of the class **TargetDataLine**, it is said :"'read(byte[] b, int off, int len)' Reads audio data from the data line's input buffer."

But where do we define it?

***Also the line of type TargetDataLine has not been attached to any mixer, so how can we know for which mixer it is for???***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `InputStream` represents a stream of bytes, where we can *read* bytes one be one (or in blocks) until it is empty. An `OutputStream` is the other direction - we *write* bytes one be one (or in blocks) until we have nothing more to write.

Streams are used to send or receive unstructured byte data.

`DataLine` handles *audio data*, in other words, bytes with a special meaning. And it offers some special methods to control the line (start/stop), get the actual format of the audio data and some other characteristics.

Comment: Hello Andreas, thanks for your answer, I have added something to my post. Could you please have a look at it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A [`DataLine`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html) is an interface related to handling sampled sound (a.k.a PCM data) in Java. I don't really know a lot of that.

An [`OutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) is an interface that represents anything that can get bytes written to it. A simple sample of an `OutputStream` is a [`FileOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html): all bytes written to that stream will be written to the file it was opened for.

An [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) is the other end: it's an interface that represents anything from which bytes can be read. A simple sample of an `InputStream` is a [`FileInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html): it can be used to read the data from a file.

So if you were to read audio data from the hard disk, you'd eventually use a `FileInputStream` to read the data. If you manipulate it and later want to write the resulting data back to the hard disk, you'd use a `FileOutputStream` to do the actual writing.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. In fact, I should treat the sound stream in real-time. It is like I should use the microphone of the computer to capture the sound first, then I do some action according to the processing result of the captured sound info.

Comment: While Line and subinterfaces from the sound api are interfaces, InputStream and OutputStream are concrete classes that only implement certain interfaces like closeable and flushable.